# Error while logging into salesforce using Google Oauth

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, login-errors, open-id-connect

We have our Org connected with google using open-id configuration. When User tries to log in to Salesforce using Google, the system checks for the user's gmail id in slaesforce user profile and if it matches, it allows the user to log in. If the user is a new user, based on the user's account settings, a user access will be automatically created by taking google id from account.
Till now everything has worked fine. But we have created a new user and when we tried to login with that user access, we are getting following error 
**"Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app. This app has not been yet verified by Google in order to use google sign in**"
Please find the attached screenshot for the same below

[image]

Can anyone please help we resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already ask in my knowledge. Please do research before asking question.
check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509667/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app

Comment: I found that question but that didnt help me solving my requirement. As that thread is closed, I tried asking another time which can give me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue as I have figured out that the issue is with Google permissions for the user